# Launching a Service in a background thread via PendingIntent

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, android-pendingintent, background-thread

I am trying to explore the world of `Services` in Android and I just wrote a small example where the activity has a button that triggers a notification.

The steps I do are:

- Creating `Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);`
- Inserting this in a `PendingIntent` and sending it to the `NotificationManager`

Then, once I click on the notification, the service (`MyService`) is started and launches a music soundtrack.

Using logging I saw that the click of the button and the actions of `MyService` both happen on the main thread, and I would like to know how can I make the service run in a separate background thread

p.s. `MyService` is extending `Service` and not `IntentService` because this last one terminates once executed

Answer (score 0):

`onStartCommand()` is called on the main thread in your `Service`. If you want to launch a background `Thread` to do the work, you can just create your own `Thread` and start it inside `onStartCommand()`. Something like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
        // Put whatever code you want to run in background thread here
    }
}).start();
```

Make sure that you have code that will shutdown running background threads if necessary when your `Service` needs to stop.

Comment: Thank you David, I will try that :) I thought that it was the whole Service that needed to be launched in a separate Thread

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever work with RXjava?

1-get the librery:
Write these two lines in the build.gradle:

> compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
>
> compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.2'

2-Write these lines in onStartCommand:

```
    io.reactivex.Observable.just(s).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                                    .subscribe(new io.reactivex.Observer<String>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onNext(@NonNull String s) {

                                                            //Write what you want here!! ;)

                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete() {

                                                        }
                                                    });
```

and inside onNext write what ever you want, and it will execute on background thread

I hope it will be helpful

Comment: thank you Mostafa, back then I was trying to do it without external libraries :)